# Perforce, how can I determine changelist of last sync

Tags: perforce

How can I determine the changelist my workarea was last synced to, regardless of which options were used by tha last 'p4 sync' (-f, -k, etc....).

I don't think its 'p4 changes -m 1 #have' (that's the revision of the client, correct ?).  I observed what 'p4 changes -m 1 #have was, did a sync (got some updated files), observed again and it didn't change.  And I can't see any others in 'p4 help revisions' that look like this.

I don't think topic "Determining the last changelist synced to in Perforce" answers this question as it seems to solve a problem for an automatic build system (which is not what I'm doing).

Thanks in Advance for any help !

Answer (score 2):

`p4 changes -m1 #have` should get you something similar to the right answer.  Note that what that will tell you exactly is: "among all of the revisions in my workspace, and all of the associated changelist numbers, which is the highest one?"  So if you synced ONE file from the latest changelist, but a bunch of other files are unsynced, you'll get the latest change even though you're not synced to it.  You'll also miss changelists that consist solely of deleted files (since you don't #have those).

The `p4 cstat` command will give you more thorough information on a per-change basis, telling you for each change whether you've synced all, some, or none of it.

Comment: Hi, In my Jenkins SCM scripted pipeline running in groovy sandbox, there is a pipeline stage to sync the perforce workspace to the jenkins workspace which is done using the p4.run("sync") and there Perforce plugin installed in Jenkins. This works but I also want to find changelist number of this perticular sync. p4.run("sync") sometimes prints out the changelist number to jenkins console but I want to access it within the pipeline script.

Comment: I ran into a case where `p4 cstat` suffers from delete only changelist gotcha. (n-1)th changelist deletes a file and changelist n is a merge from another stream which still has that file and user accepts target so that the file doesn't show up due to merge. If you now `p4 sync ...@n-1` , `p4 cstat` says `have` for n. The net result is *ok* in this case because n doesn't do anything (deletes already deleted file).

Comment: I just created a client in the same stream as the example above and didn't sync anything to it. `p4 cstsat` status says `need` on every change except change n which it says `have`.  It is as if p4 is comparing every change to the change before it to decide the status.

Comment: `cstat` essentially tells you: for each change, if you synced to this change, would it give you anything you don't already have?  A change with only delete revisions won't sync anything to an empty workspace so you essentially already "have" it even though nothing is synced.